# Append form not add files object and return (binary)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some problems with my multi-upload files code. I want to send my files object in post request but in the console but I get 0: (binary), 1: (binary)... instead of my files object. When I add `console.log` to my `for ( var key in this.attachments )` everything is okey and variable attachments is not empty. Have you idea how solve it?

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            body: null,
            attachments: [],
            form: new FormData
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filesChange(e) {
            let selectedFiles = e.target.files;

            if(!selectedFiles.length) {
                return false;
            }

            for(let i=0; i<selectedFiles.length; ++i) {
                this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
        },
        submit() {
            for ( var key in this.attachments ) {
                this.form.append(key, this.attachments[key]);
            }

            const config = { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
            this.form.append('body', this.body);

            axios.post(`/api/question/${this.questionID}/reply`, this.form, config)
            .then(res => {

            })
        }
    }
}
```